Did the US send 14,000 Mk84 2000lbs bombs to Israel between Oct 2023 and June 2024?
I've seen this reported by Reuters at the end of June:

Between the war's start last October and recent days, the United States has transferred at least 14,000 of the MK-84 2,000-pound bombs, 6,500 500-pound bombs, 3,000 Hellfire precision-guided air-to-ground missiles, 1,000 bunker-buster bombs, 2,600 air-dropped small-diameter bombs, and other munitions, according to the officials, who were not authorized to speak publicly.

But I'm slightly skeptical because such a large number of bombs probably would have required the DoD to report it (separately -- value over $25m), but I can only find some such reports about some 13,981 120mm tank shells (worth $106.5 million) and 57,021 155mm artillery rounds (worth $147.5 million).
Ah, I missed one detail "but the limit rises to $100m for other “defense articles” like bombs". I suppose that makes it more plausible if the bombs were in several installments. Sill, is there no (more) official record of it?

N.B. there's a second round of tank shells approved in August worth $774.1 million. But these are for 2027 anyway.
